# JavaScript array malformed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, javascript-objects

** Question has been updated. I do not believe it to be a duplicate. **

See Chrome console screenshot, it appears that in one state the results array is length 0, however after expanding it in the console it reveals it's actually length 1.

[image: strange console output]

The tooltip for [i] reads: "The object state below is captured upon first expansion"

Unfortunately I am under NDA and am limited in regard to what I can share.

The site is using AngularJS, and the console logs are outputting `$scope.theObject` from within the `TheRightCtrl` controller. The value of `$scope.theObject` is not modified between the above two console logs.

```
<div ng-controller="TheRightCtrl">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="thing in theObject.results">{{ thing.name }}</li>
</ul>
</div>
{{ theObject.results.length }}
```

The above view uses the controller to output a list of everything in `$scope.theObject.results` and display the length at the end. This works fine, it outputs 1 list item and binds the number 1 underneath.

In the controller it evaluates `$scope.theObject.results` length as 0 (incorrect), but in the view it evaluates it as 1 (correct).

What could be causing this discrepancy between controller and view?

Comment: No, the language is not broken if that's what you're asking. The browser `console.log()` mechanism however can play tricks on you.

Comment: You may not be able to share the source code but you could certainly create a fiddle that reproduces this problem no? Also, what browser are you using?

Comment: Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));` instead. This a very crude way to force a deference of the object and print a copy instead. `console.log` is not 'synchronous'. If the object changes it will change in the console.

Comment: The console (in Chrome anyways) keeps a reference to the object, if you modify the object after logging it, and then expand it in the console you will see the up-to-date version. However the summary at the top will not be updated.

Comment: Read the tooltip for the `i` icon.

Comment: Somebody should make sure your client understands that if they're serving the code on the Internet, the code will be public.

Comment: Yes I'm sure the client knows, but it's an NDA, it's my job, I'm not going to risk anything. Note I've updated the question above and added some details to focus it on the issue.